# Create a .zip folder and add files to it in C++ MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, zip, filepath

I am working on an C++ MFC project and one step is to create a large zip file with many other files inside it which may have different paths

As of right now, I have a vector that correctly stores all the file paths as `CString`s to each file I will need to collect and add to the zip file

The way I am thinking to tackle this is by creating an empty zip file in a specified folder such as: `C:\foo1\foo2\foo3` . The zip file would be titled `foo4.zip`, so its path would be `C:\foo1\foo2\foo3\foo4`

Then I would add each file one at a time by iterating through the vector containing the file paths  with a for loop

Is it possible to create an empty zip file and add files to it ? If so, how ? Or should I create  a regular folder, add files to it, then zip the folder after storing all files ? Or maybe I could create a zip file while supplying it the vector or file paths ?

Which is the better option in which situation and **how** do I accomplish this in C++ MFC ?

I have done some research on the `ZipFile` Class in [Microsoft's Online Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile?view=net-6.0) but from my understanding, this Class expects all the files to be zipped to be in the same folder, but in my situation, these files are scattered across many different folders.

Comment: I don't think Windows has a native c++ library or COM for *deflate* algorithm. You might consider using a third party c++ zip library.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no API that would allow creating a ZIP archive. The [compression API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cmpapi/-compression-portal) operates on single files only. The `ZipFile` type is part of the .NET framework, not the operating system.

Comment: @IInspectable That Compression Api works only on Microsoft's made up formats such as [mszip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cmpapi/using-the-compression-api), which is not compatible with zip, and is not as good. The .net link posted by Husam seems to support [*Deflate*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression?view=net-6.0) for standard zip and gz files. I don't know what API they use.

Comment: You can also consider 7zip, it's a free and open-source utility. It can be invoked from the command-line, which accepts options and the filenames - it even accepts a list-file (files to include). It can be called from your app using the `CreateProcess()` function - you should also examine its exit-code to check if it run successfully. Take a look and see if it's OK to you. We have used it for years in banking applications. As far as development is concerned, all you have to do is construct the command-line (and possibly the list-file) and invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the **ZipArchive library** which is freely available here:

https://www.artpol-software.com/

It has excellent help documentation (via download) and you can create zips, add files to zips etc and has full progress monitoring support.

Used it for several years. Later on I will update my answer with sample code.

---

### Single File

```
try
{
    rZipArchive.AddNewFile(strFile, CZipCompressor::levelDefault, false);
}
catch (CZipException* e_)
{
    const gsl::not_null<CZipException*> e{ e_ };
    e->ReportError();
    AfxMessageBox(e->GetErrorDescription(), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    e->Delete();
}
```

### Multiple Files

```
rZipArchive.AddNewFiles(strFullPath, strFileSpec, false, CZipCompressor::levelDefault, false);
```

### Creating the Zip

Admittedly I have not included the progress callback class as it is fairly easy to write and would be bespoke to your application.

But this code gives you a flavour of what you can do:

```
    try
    {
        // Create archive and set basic details
        zipArchive.Open(strBackupPath, CZipArchive::zipCreate);
        zipArchive.SetGlobalComment(_T("xxx"));
        zipArchive.SetRootPath(theApp.GetWorkingPath());

        /* ================================================ */
        CMultiProgressCallback callback;

        callback.SetProgressCtrl(&m_ProgressBackupRestore);
        callback.SetProgressTextWnd(GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC_PROGRESS_FILENAME));
        callback.SetProgressPercentTextWnd(&m_lblProgressBackupRestore);

        zipArchive.SetCallback(&callback,
            CZipActionCallback::cbMultiAdd | CZipActionCallback::cbCalculateForMulti);

        zipArchive.AddNewFile(strRegPath, CZipCompressor::levelDefault, false);

        /* ================================================ */
        // Build group filter
        ZipArchiveLib::CGroupFileFilter groupFilter;

        // Files to include
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("*.*")).release());

        // Files to exclude
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("exp*.htm"), true).release());   // Preview in Browser
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("mwe*.xml"), true).release());   // Meeting Workbook Editor
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("mwp*.xml"), true).release());   // Meeting Workbook Print
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("sre*.xsl"), true).release());   // Sound Rota Editor
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("srt*.xsl"), true).release());   // Sound Rota Temp
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("gcal_*.tmp"), true).release()); // Google Calendar Temp
        groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("*.bin3"), true).release());     // Outlook OAuth Cache
        zipArchive.AddNewFiles(theApp.GetWorkingPath(), groupFilter, false, CZipCompressor::levelDefault, false);
        /* ================================================ */

        /* ================================================ */
        // AJT v20.1.7 — Backup mode
        if (eBackupWhat == COtherSettingsAutomaticBackupPage::EnumBackupWhat::Complete)
        {
            // Reset
            groupFilter.Clear();

            // Files to include
            groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("*.*")).release());

            // Files to exclude
            groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("exp*.htm"), true).release()); // Preview in Browser
            groupFilter.Add(std::make_unique<ZipArchiveLib::CNameFileFilter>(_T("mwa*.xml"), true).release()); // Meeting Workbook Assignment slips
            zipArchive.AddNewFiles(theApp.GetWorkingPath() + _T("AssignmentSlips"),
                                   groupFilter,                     // Files to include
                                   true,                            // Recursive
                                   CZipCompressor::levelDefault,    // Compression level
                                   false);                          // Skip initial path
        }
        /* ================================================ */

        auto zipCloseResult = zipArchive.Close();
    }
    catch (CZipException* e_)
    {
        const gsl::not_null<CZipException*> e{ e_ };
        zipArchive.Close(CZipArchive::afAfterException);

        e->ReportError();
        bExported = false;
        e->Delete();
    }
    catch (CException *e_)
    {
        const gsl::not_null<CException*> e{ e_ };

        zipArchive.Close(CZipArchive::afAfterException);

        // Problem - tell user
        e->ReportError();
        bExported = false;
        e->Delete();
    }

    if (bExported)
        AfxMessageBox(IDS_STR_SETTINGS_SAVED, MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

}
```

---

The ZipArchive library does have a commercial version where you pay for a license but in my case I did not need to purchase one. This is what it says:

> The open source version of the ZipArchive Library is licensed under [GNU GPL](https://www.artpol-software.com/ZipArchive/KB/gpl.aspx).

When you download the library you need to build the right version to create your required LIB or DLL for use with your application. Several Visual Studio platform files are provided. Just pick the one you need.